# Java Swing to iText and vice versa font equalization

Tags: java, swing, fonts, itext

So I'm asking this question somewhat again, but this time with some more info...

I use same *.tff file for both fonts. If you request it, I'll upload it somewhere and put it up for download here.

This is my code for Java Swing font:

```
static Font loadFont(String fontName, float size)
    {
        try
        {
            Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(fontName+".ttf"));
            font = font.deriveFont(size);

            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);

            return font;
        }

        catch (FontFormatException | IOException e)
        {
            //TODO error message
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I just set it in JTextArea.

This is my code for iText font:

```
public static BaseFont loadiTextFont(String fontName)
{
    try
    {           
        return BaseFont.createFont(Utils.class.getResource(fontName+".ttf").toString(), BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, false);
    }

    catch (DocumentException | IOException e)
    {
        //TODO error message
        return null;
    }
}
```

I just use it in this line: `PdfContentByte.setFontAndSize(font, size);`

If I want the font size to be equal for both Swing and iText, I use this formula:

`iTextFontSize = 0.74 * swingFontSize`

which is a result from a bit of pixel-unit-dpi calculating.

Doing that makes the font heights equal. However, the row lengths differ and they differ inconsistently. Sometimes Swing row is wider than iText row, sometimes it's the opposite.

I know it's not a problem with widths[], I tried calcualting what it should be and what it is and the results matched.

So, what else is there that could make fonts so different from each other?

And if there is an attribute that I could change, it would be nice if you showed me the code to change it either on swing or iText, or both if that's the nature of it (as would kerning be, since I'd have to turn it off on both fonts).

I believe Mr. Lowagie could know the best what else could it possibly be.

Comment: *"I use same ..tff file for both fonts."*  How big is it (in bytes)?  What i it called?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: 811 052 bytes. It's called calibri.ttf, but I don't know why does it matter... You don't need a SSCCE. You have the font-setup code. If you have an idea(s) which you think will help, tell me what to change about or add to the code and I'll try it and report back... Kindof a community brainstorming... I'd do it myself, but I'm not that familiar with the font stuff..